# MSSQL2016 UPDATE trigger to INSERT record in other table based on SUM of bit column

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2016

I'm attempting to automate our order status update system.  Here is the flow we have in place:

1. orders come in to our system as one order (via FTP file), and get split into 2 or more orders (inserted into SplitOrdersHeader_tb)
2. resulting multiple orders are sent from the SplitOrders tables (header and detail) to ERP system
3. ERP system produces order confirmations for each order (inserted into OrderConfirmationHeader_tb, and detail table)
4. need to update *original* single order status after *all* split order confirmations have been received

Here are the tables involved:

```
CREATE TABLE SplitOrdersHeader_tb(
    OriginalCustomerPONumber varchar(20),
    NewCustomerPONumber varchar(20),
    Company varchar(2),
    CustomerNumber varchar(10),
    OrderProcessed bit DEFAULT 0,
    OrderMoved bit DEFAULT 0,
    OrderConfirmationReceived bit DEFAULT 0
)

CREATE TABLE OrderConfirmationHeader_tb(
    MasterOrderNumber varchar(20),
    CustomerPONumber varchar(20),
    Company varchar(2),
    CustomerNumber varchar(10)
)

CREATE TABLE UpdateOtherSystem_tb(
    OriginalCustomerPONumber varchar(20)
)
```

I have a trigger on the OrderConfirmationHeader_tb that updates the status of each split order, once the order confirmations have been loaded:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.INSERT_Update_SplitOrderConfirmations_tg
    ON dbo.OrderConfirmationHeader_tb
    AFTER INSERT
    AS

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    BEGIN
        UPDATE SOH
        SET SOH.OrderConfirmationReceived = 1,
            SOH.MasterOrderNumber = LTRIM(RTRIM(I.MasterOrderNumber))
        FROM OrderSplitting.SplitOrdersHeader_tb SOH
            INNER JOIN inserted I ON SOH.CustomerNumber = I.Customer
                AND SOH.NewCustomerPONumber = I.Reference
                AND SOH.Company = I.Company 
                AND SOH.OrderProcessed = 1
                AND SOH.OrderMoved = 1
    END
```

What I'm wanting to do is create an UPDATE trigger on the SplitOrdersHeader_tb that will:
- count the number of split orders from the original CustomerPONumber
- sum the number of OrderConfirmationReceived values
- if COUNT = SUM then insert a new record into UpdateOtherSystem_tb, provided the MasterOrderNumber does not already exist in the UpdateOtherSystem_tb

I have this, but it feels way too clunky:

```
CREATE TRIGGER OrderSplitting.UPDATE_Update_WCO_Status_tg
    ON OrderSplitting.SplitOrdersHeader_tb
    AFTER UPDATE AS

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    BEGIN
        DECLARE @NEW_CUSTOMER_PO_NUMBER varchar(255),
                @ORIGINAL_CUSTOMER_PO_NUMBER varchar(255),
                @COUNT_OF_ORDER_HEADERS int,
                @TOTAL_CONFIRMED_ORDERS int

        SELECT @NEW_CUSTOMER_PO_NUMBER = NewCustomerPONumber
        FROM inserted

        SELECT @ORIGINAL_CUSTOMER_PO_NUMBER = OriginalCustomerPONumber,
                @COUNT_OF_ORDER_HEADERS = COUNT(*),
                @TOTAL_CONFIRMED_ORDERS = SUM(CAST(OrderConfirmationReceived as int))
        FROM OrderSplitting.SplitOrdersHeader_tb
        WHERE OriginalCustomerPONumber IN (SELECT OriginalCustomerPONumber
                                            FROM OrderSplitting.SplitOrdersHeader_tb
                                            WHERE NewCustomerPONumber = @NEW_CUSTOMER_PO_NUMBER)
        GROUP BY OriginalCustomerPONumber

        IF @COUNT_OF_ORDER_HEADERS = @TOTAL_CONFIRMED_ORDERS
            BEGIN
                BEGIN TRY
                    INSERT INTO OrderSplitting.UpdateOtherSystem_tb(OriginalCustomerPONumber)
                    VALUES(@ORIGINAL_CUSTOMER_PO_NUMBER)
                END TRY

                BEGIN CATCH
                    DECLARE @ERROR_MESSAGE varchar(MAX)
                    SET @ERROR_MESSAGE = ERROR_MESSAGE()

                    EXEC msdb..sp_send_dbmail
                            @recipients = <app_support>,
                            @subject = 'Update Trigger Error',
                            @body = @ERROR_MESSAGE
                END CATCH
            END
    END
```

Comment: The current trigger will only deal with single row updates, i.e.: `inserted` can contain multiple rows and the `select @NEW_CUSTOMER_PO_NUMBER = NewCustomerPONumber from inserted` deals with only one of those rows. What happens if two or more rows get updated at the same time?

Comment: That's another problem I ran across earlier, but thought i was just seeing things.  Now that someone else has pointed it out too, I am really at a loss as to how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have something, but would like some additional feedback, please:

```
CREATE TRIGGER OrderSplitting.UPDATE_Update_WCO_Status_tg
    ON OrderSplitting.SplitOrdersHeader_tb
    AFTER UPDATE AS

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    BEGIN TRY
        INSERT INTO OrderSplitting.UpdateOtherSystem_tb(OriginalCustomerPONumber)
            SELECT SOH.OriginalCustomerPONumber
            FROM OrderSplitting.SplitOrdersHeader_tb SOH
                INNER JOIN inserted I ON SOH.OriginalCustomerPONumber = I.OriginalCustomerPONumber
                LEFT OUTER JOIN OrderSplitting.UpdateOtherSystem_tb UOS ON SOH.OriginalCustomerPONumber = UOS.OriginalCustomerPONumber
            WHERE UOS.OriginalCustomerPONumber IS NULL
            GROUP BY SOH.OriginalCustomerPONumber
            HAVING COUNT(SOH.OriginalCustomerPONumber) = SUM(CAST(SOH.OrderConfirmationReceived as int))
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
        DECLARE @ERROR_MESSAGE varchar(MAX)
        SET @ERROR_MESSAGE = ERROR_MESSAGE()

        EXEC msdb..sp_send_dbmail
        @recipients = <app_support>,
        @subject = 'Update Trigger Error',
        @body = @ERROR_MESSAGE
    END CATCH
```